# Divisor Topology is path-connected

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that the divisor topology is path-connected. This is the set $X=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ where the open sets are the set of unions of the sets $U_n = \{d \in X : d |n\}$.

So for any $N,M \in X$ I need to find a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to X$ such that $f(0)=N$ and $f(1)=M$. Hmmm, so I have thought maybe of splitting $[0,1]$ up and having a kind of step function between $N$ and $M$. I just need to make sure it is continuous at the "jumps". I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: @Dzoooks Apologies for being unclear. The open sets are defined to be the set of unions of the sets $U_n$.

Comment: In the case $N,M$ are composite, take $$f(x)= N\cdot 1_{x<1/2} + M\cdot 1_{1/2 \leq x \leq 1}.$$  There aren't any open sets in the image to check.  In the case one or both is prime, you may have to modify this a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m,n\in X$, with $m\ne n$.

Define $f:[0,1]\to X$ by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
m&\;\;\text{if}\;x\in[0,\frac{1}{3})\\[4pt]
mn&\;\;\text{if}\;x\in[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]\\[4pt]
n&\;\;\text{if}\;x\in(\frac{2}{3},1]
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $f(0)=m$, and $f(1)=n$.

To verify that $f$ is continuous . . .

Without loss of generality, assume $m < n$, and let $A=\{m,mn,n\}$.

As a subspace of $X$, the open subsets of $A$ are
$$\varnothing,\;\{m\},\;\{n\},\;\{m,n\},\;A$$
unless $m{\mid\,}n,\;$in which case, the open subsets of $A$ are
$$\varnothing,\;\{m\},\;\{m,n\},\;A$$

In either case, it's easily verified that if $U$ is open in $A$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$.